# Change Salesforce license to Chatter Free / Chatter Only User

Tags: user-management

By mistakenly I created a user as Salesforce Licensed User. Now I need to delete/change the license, which i tried change but couldn't. Is there a way to change since we cannot delete a user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible. Please refer to this article

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KUIzAAO

Try logging a case.

Similarly,

You can't convert a Chatter Only license or any other standard Salesforce licenses to a Chatter Free license. You can, however, deactivate the Chatter Only user and create a new Chatter Free user with a unique username. The history remains with the Chatter Only user.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_faq_chatterplus_downgrade_to_chatter_free.htm&language=en_US